# Converting the FormData() to an object

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```js
const formSubmit = (e) => {
  console.log("form submitted")
  e.preventDefault()
  const formData = new FormData(e.target)
  console.log(formData.get('firstName'))
  console.log(formData.get('lastName'))
}

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', formSubmit)
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="firstName" />
  <input name="lastName" />
  <button type="submit"> Create User </button>
</form>
```

I want to be able to access firstName and lastName as simple as:

```js
console.log(formData.firstName)
console.log(formData.lastName)
```

However, I can't, because `new FormData()` returns something (I'm not sure which data type it returns, a map?).

How to convert this retuned value to an object, so I can access its properties as simple as described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, all you have to do is to use

```
Object.fromEntries(formData)
```

ex:

```js
const formSubmit = (e) => {
  console.log("form submitted")
  e.preventDefault()
  const formData = new FormData(e.target)
  console.log(Object.fromEntries(formData))
}

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', formSubmit)
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="firstName" />
  <input name="lastName" />
  <button type="submit"> Create User </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

so FormData() create new object with methods [more about API FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)
and here You have [more about Date and methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).
I hope this helps.

```js
const userForm = document.querySelector('form');

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const userFormData = new FormData(event.target);
    const today = new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'UTC'});
    userFormData.append('date', today);

    userFormData.forEach((value, key) => {
        console.log(key, value);
    });
};

userForm.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
```

```html
<form method="post" action="">
    <input name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First name"/>
    <input name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last name"/>
    <button typu="submit">Create new User</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Object.formEntries() can trick you into thinking that you are getting all data, unless you read the [documentation][1]. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries

I had a similar problem writing a unit test to check what I was sending to an API from FormData.

FormData is practically and array containing [key, value] tuples. That means that if you have array data inside your form the values you would have gotten from FormData.getAll(key) that reaturns an array of the values, would result in a flat key:value in the Object.

Additionally the typing for the FormData may require you to for instance translate number values to strings before you can pass them into the FormData.append function, that you need to use if you have multiple values with the same key.

So getting all the values out of a FormData, if you just want to read them in the console:

```
    // setup:
let formData = new FormData();
let myInitialObject = {a:1, b:[2,3], c:"4"};
// Populate the formData:
Object.keys(myInitialObject).forEach(key => {
if(Array.isArray(myInitialObject[key])){
myInitialObject[key].forEach(value => {formData.append(key, String(value))})
    }
else {
    formData.set(key, String(myInitialObject[key]))
    }
});

// to just see the formData:
formData.forEach((value, key) => console.log('key:', key, 'values:', value))
// key: a values: 1
// key: b values: 2
// key: b values: 3
// key: c values: 4
// notice that there are two b's
Object.fromEntries(formData) // returns {a: '1', b: '3', c: '4'}
```